# How to create large similarity matrix as a sparse one, from partitioning data?

Tags: r, sparse-matrix, similarity

I have a vector representing a partitioning of objects into clusters:

```
#9 objects partitioned into 6 clusters
> part1 <- c(1,2,3,1,4,2,2,5,6)
```

I can easily create similarity matrix where the measure of similarity is just {0,1}: 0 if two elements are in different clusters, and 1, if in the same:

```
> sim <- outer(part1,part1,"==")
> sim
       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]  [,7]  [,8]  [,9]
 [1,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [2,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
 [3,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [4,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [5,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [6,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
 [7,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
 [8,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
 [9,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

But for large vectors (100,000's of objects) it doesn't work due to memory limits.
Clusters are small on average, so sparse matrix would be compact enough. I've looked through Matrix package and couldn't find anything like `outer()` for sparse objects.

So is there any other simple way to create such matrix directly from the vector (without looping through all vector's elements' pairs and populating  sparse matrix element by element)?